# Javascript Modal Box OnCommand not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
        <div>
            
                    <asp:Repeater ID="ProductView" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" >
        
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblAddressID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("OrderNumer") %>' Visible = "false" />
                                         
                                         <asp:LinkButton ID="Delete" CssClass="MordersButton"  OnCommand="btnDelete_Click" OnClientClick="return ShowMessage();" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Delete") %>'></asp:LinkButton></h5>
                                    
        
                        </ItemTemplate>
        
                    </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
                    function ConfirmBox(msgtitle, message, controlToFocus) {
                        $("#msgDialogAlert").dialog({
                            autoOpen: false,
                            modal: true,
                            title: msgtitle,
                            closeOnEscape: true,
                            buttons: [{
                                text: "Yes",
                                click: function () {
                                    
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                    if (controlToFocus != null)
                                        controlToFocus.focus();
                                    
                                    
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                text: "No",
                                click: function () {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                    if (controlToFocus != null)
                                        controlToFocus.focus();
                                    
                                }
                            }],
                            close: function () {
                                $("#operationMsgAlert").html("");
                                if (controlToFocus != null)
                                    controlToFocus.focus();
                            },
                            show: { effect: "clip", duration: 200 }
                        });
                        $("#operationMsgAlert").html(message);
                        $("#msgDialogAlert").dialog("open");
                    };
    
                    function ShowMessage() {
                        ConfirmBox("This is Title - Please Confirm", "Are you sure you wanted to delete? This cannot be undone!", null);
                        return false;
                    }
        </script>

 protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = (sender as LinkButton).Parent as RepeaterItem;
        string name = (item.FindControl("Delete") as LinkButton).Text.Trim();
        string OrderNumber = (item.FindControl("lblAddressID") as Label).Text.Trim();
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DC_ManageOrders_Update"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryType", name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNumber", OrderNumber);
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
            }
        }
        this.FlavorImage1Bind();
    }
```

If I Click the button Yes after the modal box opened the delete is not happening. Please help how can i achieve this
i want to run the btnDelete_Click code to delete the record, without modal box through normal javascript i can able to delete the record.
If someone able to help me it will be very usefull to me ...

Comment: Return true if user chooses yes.

Comment: @Crowcoder - Not working Return true, Please explain me briefly if you dont mind

Comment: Check [this article out](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-to-use-preventdefault-vs-return-false-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem here?

When you use onClientClick, you "goal" is to return true (server side code runs), or false - server side button event does not run.

So, you can say use a js confirm box. That's because confirm() HALTS the code.

However, jquery.UI, and in FACT MOST web based software does NOT halt code. Most web based controls (bootstrap dialogs, and jQuery.UI) are NOT modal. They are asynchronous  in operation. Blocking, or halting code in js is simple RARE allowed these days.

So, most suggested solutions center around say disabling the event code for the button, and then you execute a _doPostBack(). This is not bad, but then you can't have that button conditional run based on return of true/false. So you wind up with a extra button, extra _doPoast back. So most solutions are really quite poor.

So, when this code runs:

```
OnClientClick="return ShowMessage();
```

The above code runs async - does NOT wait. So the dialog pops, but the code continues running and the server side button click will fire!! - (and the dialog that was displayed will of course colipase since we have a page post back.

So, we want:

```
avoid document ready solutions - they are horrid to debug
document ready means we have a VERY difficult time following code flow.

we want a simple function - has to return true/false.
but, jQuery.UI dialogs do not wait, and they don't halt code.
```

So, to avoid world poverty, 2-3 extra routines, messy _doPostback, and code to disable the button?

Do it this way:

Adopt a code standard that you create a true/false var of the SAME name of the function (with "OK" on the end), and scope the variable to that function.

Also, I assume that the delete button when clicked (without the onclientclick) works as you wish.

```
<script>
   var mypopok = false;     // runs on browser load

   function mypop() {

      if (mypopok) {
           return true;
      }

      mydiv = $('#dlg1');
      mydiv.dialog({
         autoOpen: false, modal: true, title: 'Yes/no test', width: '250px',
                    position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+150' },
                    buttons: {
                        'ok': function () {
                            mypopok = true;
                            mydiv.dialog('close');
                            $('#Button1').click();
                        },
                        'cancel': function () {
                            mydiv.dialog('close')
                        }
                    }
                });
                // Open the dialog
                // if dialog has MORE then just ok, cancel, and say has text
                // box, check box in content, then you MUST move back to form
                mydiv.parent().appendTo($("form:first"))
                mydiv.dialog('open')
                return false;
            }
        </script>
```

Now, the button click code looks like this:

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="48px" Text="Button" Width="171px" 
             ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="return mypop();"/>
```

So what will occur?

You will click on the button - the code will run and return false!!! - (remember, it does NOT wait or halt). Now the dialog does pops, but button event code will not trigger.

Based on yes or no, we set that bol flag to true or false. If cancel, then we just close the dialog. If "ok", then we set the flag = true and RE-CLICK the SAME button. Now the button click runs again, but we in our routine return true before the pop dialog code runs, and thus now the server side event click runs.

We:

```
 did not have to consider using await (promise)
 did not have to add a extra button
 did not have document ready and code ALL OVER in the page
 did not have to add extra buttons and events.
 code is liner - easy to read - all in one spot.
```

Now I would consider adding the parameters to the Actual OnClientClick,

Say like this:

```
 OnClientClick="return mypop('This is Title - Please Confirm',
    'Are you sure you wanted to delete? This cannot be undone!', null);"
```

And add the parms to the mypop.

You can't really use two routines like you have, since as noted this:

```
         function ShowMessage() {
                    ConfirmBox("This is Title - Please Confirm", "Are you sure you wanted to delete? This cannot be undone!", null);
                    return false;
                }
```

Confirmbox does NOT halt or wait - the code will "run right though" and immediate return false.

So use the flag trick I outline, and re-click the SAME button again when user hits ok. That way, you don't wire up 3-4 routines, and you don't need to add extra buttons or use _DoPostBack() in the js code.

Comment: Thanks After some modification as per my requirement it working fine, your code help me a lot thank you so much @albert D. Kallal